# sql query not bringing back correct records

Tags: sql, join

I've got a sql query which should bring back records based on certain values not matching. In my BaseStock table I've got actualQty(int) and baseQty(int). In another table I've got the ordersQty (which is worked out based on the actualQty and baseQty). The orderQty will be baseQty - actualQty.

Placing the order it will take the baseQty - actualQty to make the orderQty. But if the order is already placed and the orderQty + actualQty = baseQty it should not bring back those records.

The query I've made doesn't bring back any records.....
This is what I have done:

```
    SELECT BS.[ID],BS.[WarehouseNo],BS.[Customer],BS.[Site],BS.[VendorNo],BS.[Description],
  BS.[ActualQty],BS.[BaseQty], (BS.[BaseQty] - BS.[ActualQty]) AS PlaceOrderQty
   FROM [dbo].[StockControlBaseStock] AS BS
   RIGHT JOIN [dbo].[StockControlStockOrder] AS SO
   ON BS.ID = SO.BaseStockRef
   WHERE (BS.[ActualQty] + SO.OrderQTY) <> BS.[BaseQty]
   AND BS.[ActualQty] IS NOT NULL
   AND BS.[BaseQty] IS NOT NULL
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you post sql fiddle for this?

Comment: my apologies, not sure what a sql fiddle is?

Comment: if you go to sqlfiddle.com then you can create tables and insert values and run select statement to see output. Its virtual database you can say. When you create those tables then provide us link of that fiddle. one of working fiddle is like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0b33/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try the following solution?

```
SELECT BS.[ID],BS.[WarehouseNo],BS.[Customer],BS.[Site],BS.[VendorNo],BS.[Description],
BS.[ActualQty],BS.[BaseQty], (BS.[BaseQty] - BS.[ActualQty]) AS PlaceOrderQty
FROM [dbo].[StockControlBaseStock] AS BS
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[StockControlStockOrder] AS SO
ON BS.ID = SO.BaseStockRef
WHERE (BS.[ActualQty] + Iif(SO.OrderQTY IS NULL, 0, SO.OrderQTY)) <> BS.[BaseQty]
AND BS.[ActualQty] IS NOT NULL
AND BS.[BaseQty] IS NOT NULL
```

This query returns all orders without the adequate order placed